# Semantic UI: how can I destroy table sortable?

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, semantic-ui

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$('#table_id').sortable('destory');
```

Comment: As per the documentation, it should work. But to debug it further can you provide an example of your code?